# How can I create a regular expression that includes a line feed?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[see=[^\]]*\]"); 

var list = phraseSources.ToList();

list.ForEach(item => item.JmdictMeaning = regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, ""));
```

It removes all between "[see" and "]"

However I found out that before the "[see" is a line feed and I would like to remove this in addition to all between "[see" and "]".

I used a hex editor and I can see:

```
0D 0A
```

Which I think is causing the line feed but I am not sure how to make a regex that includes this.

Can someone tell me how I can remove this plus all that comes between "[see" and "]"

Comment: Do you mean to have the equals sign in your pattern after "[see"? The last line of your question doesn't have the equals sign _" between "[see" and "]" "_. This might be causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to also include carriage returns (`0D`, aka `\r`) and line feeds (`0A`, aka `\n`)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[see=[^\]]*\]|\r\n");
```

So now it matches anything that's `[see=...]` or `\r\n`.

If you expect either of them to appear by itself in the string you could also match something like this

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[see=[^\]]*\]|[\r\n]");
```

It would clean up any `\r` and `\n` characters even if they appear alone.

If you meant that you want to only remove a `\r\n` that might appear before the `[see=...` part, then this would do

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\r\n)?\[see=[^\]]*\]");
```

Comment: Hello, I only want to remove the \r\n if it appears before [see  so am I correct in saying your last regex is the one?

Comment: Hello, I just noticed that  the regex is changing [see ...] to ]  where the ... represent any string. Do you have any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: @Alan2 can you give an example input and output string?